# How to Search Second Array Data in First Array Data?

Tags: php, arrays

In php, i am new in php anybody help me for this?
i have two arrays , in `Array2` i have two records, i want to check Data of `Array2` whether in `Array1` or not , how can i check the data of `Array2` in `Array1` its available or not !

Thanks in advance

## Array1

```
    [items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [abc] => z1
                [xyz] => cool
                [val] => 2.32
                [color] => D
             )
         [1] // i have 5o records in array1
     );
```

## Array 2

```
    [items] => SearchArray
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [abc] => z1
                [xyz] => cool
                [val] => 2.32
                [color] => D
             )
         [1] // i have 2 records
     );
```

Comment: read about the function in_array() http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: @chepe263 thanks you for your replay i don't want this way,i want to do  Search Data of SearchArray['items'] from array1['items'] how can i do this ?

Comment: you could loop from one of the arrays, check if abc from array1 is in array2. If true, check the values.

Comment: @chepe263 yes i tried using loop but i don't get the results of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code - I hope it helpes some way :

```
$matches = array();

for($i2 = 0; $i2 < count($Array2); $i2++)
{
    for($i1 = 0; $i1 < count($Array1); $i1++)
    {
        $bMatch = TRUE;
        foreach($Array1[$i1] as $key => $val)
        {
            if($Array2[$i2][$key] !== $val)
            {
                $bMatch = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($bMatch)
        {
            $matches[] = array($i2, $i1);
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates through both arrays, comparing elements (which in fact are sub arrays) in such way that they are equal only if all elements of sub array from `$Array2` are equal to all elements of sub array from `$Array1`. If the match is found, the pair `($i2, $i1)` is added to the `$matches` array, so in the end, basing on your example, you would have something like:

```
$matches => array  (
               [0] => array (0, 0)
               ...
            )
```

I hope the assumption made is the proper one.

Comment: `if($Array2[$key] !== $val){$bMatch = FALSE;
                break;}` i getting error in this line in which i don't get key from array2

Comment: I;m really glad could help

Answer (score 0):

Can use **array_search** method. For more information, check out the manual reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php